# Apache redirect from cgi-bin requests

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, cgi-bin

I intend to capture url requests directed to CGI-BIN, and forward them to a different domain with the parameters, and https.

Example:

```
http://example.com/cgi-bin/scrip1.py?name=Hello
```

to

```
https://another.com/cgi-bin/script2.py?name=Hello
```

Since the requests have CGI-BIN in the link, mod_rewrite doesn't work :/

```
RewriteRule ^/cgi-bin/script1.py(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/cgi-bin/script2.py$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

It works on non-CGI requests, but fails with CGI. Am I missing something?

Note: Ideally, I would like to capture the parameters after the **script1.py**, and pass them to **script2.py**

Comment: `RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/script1\.py$ https://another.com/cgi-bin/script2.py [NC,R=301,L,QSA]`

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with a quote from [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> When using the rewrite engine in .htaccess files the per-directory
>   prefix (which always is the same for a specific directory) is
>   automatically removed for the RewriteRule pattern matching and
>   automatically added after any relative (not starting with a slash or
>   protocol name) substitution encounters the end of a rule set. See the
>   RewriteBase directive for more information regarding what prefix will
>   be added back to relative substitutions.

and

> The removed prefix always ends with a slash, meaning the matching
>   occurs against a string which never has a leading slash. Therefore, a
>   Pattern with ^/ never matches in per-directory context.

Furthermore, the url that is matched does not include the query string. Assuming you don't define a new query string, the query string is automatically caried over.

Assuming that your .htaccess is in your www-root, the following rule should do the trick:

```
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/script1.py$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/cgi-bin/script2.py [NC,R,L]
```

Change `R` in the flags to `R=301` if, and only if everything works as expected. Permanent redirects are sometimes cached by the browser, causing unexpected and impossible to debug behaviour. You want to use temporary redirects while testing.